# Running python script from python script and sending commands

Tags: python

I'm really lost reading about subprocess and pexpect and a number of other methods and have tested out a few but haven't gotten anything close to what I'm needing.

I have a two python scripts the first one is a GUI that monitors the serial data and tries to match a search condition. The second one is a python script that runs an interactive terminal and takes input from the user and performs various functions. How can I get my GUI to output commands to the second interactive script? Ideally both windows would be visible and the second one could take input from the user or from the GUI. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's traditional to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You can use [Sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) to accomplish this, however an explanation of how would be much to long for an answer on this site.

Comment: If you use subprocess: one application (master) controls the other (slave) and it is mostly a one way communication, master asks slave to perform operation and slave returns an answer. So in your user case you'd struggle to have second app receive commands from GUI AND from user.

Comment: At the end it might be just easier to integrate both programms into one and let each part run in a separate thread.